# Javac/Eclipse - Warning if a method doesn't throw the most specific Exception it could

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, javac

I have a class like this:

```
public class FooBar
{

    public String foo() throws Exception {
        return "";
    }

    public String bar() throws Exception {
        throw new BazException();
    }

}
```

Inside a eclipse, I get a warning on method `foo` stating:

> The declared exception Exception is not actually thrown by the method foo() from type FooBar

See below:

[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to configure a silmiar warning for method `bar`?  Method `bar` doesn't throw the most specific exception that it could.

I am using:

- Eclipse Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
- Java 8

Answer (score 1):

Your post is raising two distinct issues. First issue:

> Is it possible to configure a similar warning for method bar?

Yes, though no configuration is needed. If a method declares that it throws some sub-type of **Exception** but actually doesn't, then a similar warning to the one you report will be displayed in Eclipse. There is nothing special about an exception of type **Exception** with regard to that warning.

In your code just change method **foo()** to throw **BazException** instead of 
**Exception** to see that:

[image: Exception warning message]

Second issue:

> Method bar doesn't throw the most specific exception that it could.

That is true, but is an issue distinct from getting a message about an exception not being thrown at all. There is no way to configure Eclipse to throw a message like "*The method {m} does not throw the most specific exception that it could*" since there is no message along those lines in Eclipse's list of compiler Errors/Warnings.

Besides, the wording of such a message could get tricky and convoluted in a complex method that threw multiple exceptions. Perhaps a code analyzer tool such as [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) could identify offending methods for you.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question have have been slightly unclear.  Only really asking about what you labeled the "Second issue".

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude OK, understood, and therefore the answer to your question is "no", simply because Eclipse does not provide a warning for that "most specific exception" scenario you describe. (I do like the idea though.)

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Also, I checked PMD, and unfortunately it does not address your concern. FYI, you can see all the exception scenarios that PMD does handle here: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/#Strict_Exception_Rules

Answer (score 0):

**No**, Eclipse only displays a warning in the first case, because **throwing an exception that can never occur is a code smell**, whereas **throwing a more general exception is not a code smell**.

#### Throwing an exception that can never occur

This **forces the caller unnecessarily to handle the exception**, for example:

```java
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        try {
            System.out.println(foo.foo());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // unreachable code
        }
    }

    public String foo() throws IOException {
        return "";
    }

}
```

For simplified exception handling, some people prefer to add generally the `throws Exception` or the `throws Throwable` declaration to almost any method. Therefore, the warning can be configured to ignore these special cases: in *Project > Properties: Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings*, section *Unnecessary code > Unnecessary declaration of thrown exception* uncheck *Ignore 'Exception' and ' Throwable'*.

Note, if an interface method has a `throws` declaration, the implementing class does not need to have also a `throws` declaration:

```java
public class Foo implements IFoo {

    public String foo() {
        return "";
    }

}

interface IFoo {
    String foo() throws IOException;
}
```

#### Throwing a more general exception

A more general exception is useful if you want to hide details from the caller (for the same reasons you should prefer `List list = new ArrayList();` over `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();` in most cases). It gives you more flexibility to change the code of the method without having to modify the code of the caller.

However, maybe you can create problems markes with [SpotBugs](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spotbugs-eclipse-plugin), [Checkstyle](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/checkstyle-plug), [PMD](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pmd-eclipse-plugin) or similar plug-ins for that. If at all, I would recommend to do this only for private methods.

Comment: `throwing a more general exception is not a code smell.` - I view this as code smell, that is the reason that I would like to have a compiler warning or info about this.

Comment: Why is that a code smell for you? Note, there is also no inverse function for _Refactor > Generalize Declared Type_ in Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger Re "For simplified exception handling, some people prefer to add generally the throws Exception or the throws Throwable declaration to almost any method", see Efffective Java by Joshua Bloch: "...never declare that a method 'throws exception' or, worse yet, 'throws Throwable'.". I usually resist making calls to authority, but in this case I'll make an exception.

Comment: @skomisa Because there are different opinions here I wrote _"some people prefer"_. It's nothing I recommend. If no one would use it, there wouldn't be a setting for it in Eclipse and Joshua Bloch wouldn't have mentioned it. We all agree that it is good to be able to display a warning in this case. We don't agree on whether throwing a more general exception is always a code smell. My argument is, that a more general exception does not break the contract with the caller when the implementation is changed by throwing an additional specific exception.